# cross domain javascript function call?

Tags: java, javascript, cors

I have a problem to call a JS function which is in another website in another server inside the same network. My script works on the following way:

There's a form that in page from server 1 (IP: 192.168.1.17) has a button that opens one popup window from page on server 2 (IP:162.168.1.18) and shows a list of items. By double clicking in one item of the list the page executes the `opener.setearProducto` function, retrieving aString as parameter. But at this moment, Firebug shows me a message: "Error: Permission denied to access property 'setearProductos'" and the script doesn't work.
It is strange because when I test it in the same PC all works perfectly.

I was googling and noticed that need to install [CORS](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html). But when I install it in both servers the script still doesn't work. I also tried to add the header *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* to the JSP file, but didn't work either.

I don't know if the problem is related to the frameworks used in the application: Struts 2 and Spring.

I need help, because I don't know what to do.

I attach my *web.xml* if it helps.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- CORS -->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- configuraicond e Struts y Spring -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>sistema.cron.TareasProgramadas</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>sistema.base.logica.ControlServicios</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- inicio CORS -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- inicio Struts -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            120
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: *when I test it in the same PC all works perfectly* probably because your PC is allowed to access to the other server resources remotely or both web applications are deployed in the same server, thus all the permissions to share resources between them are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've missed the 'init-param' setting as follows

```
    <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>http://example.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Found [here](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html)

The reason for needing to specify this is that the browser has certain protection created so that you cannot simply make remote calls to any external site.

I recommend reading about it on the [HTML5Rocks: Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) site.  The short of it is that when you make a http POST request to an external domain, the browser will first make an http OPTIONS call with certain parameters that the server will use to determine whether or not to make the call, which the browser will then use to know if it can go ahead with the POST request.

Comment: The page you referenced is in the additional configuration section: "The CORS Filter can be run with no additional configuration in most situations...If the default public CORS mode doesn't satisfy your requirements, you can override it by specifying your own configuration." I don't know what the issue is, but I don't think that it's missing the init-param.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are violating Javascript's [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short: your browser gets the page from server 1 (IP: 192.168.1.17) but later in the process it wants to execute a script that resides in server 2 (IP: 192.168.1.18). This is a no-no in javascript land. The wikipedia article explains 3 ways you can relax this restriction.

In case you decide to go the Ajax way, there is a fourth alternative, and a personal favorite, the JSONP way.

Also I don't understand what you mean with respect to CORS when you say:

> I install it in both servers

CORS is not something you install. It's an HTTP extension where the browser that wants to violate the same-origin-policy actually tells a web server (via HTTP header extension `Origin`) that it wants to execute code inside a page that it has brought form another web server. To put it in your scenario: your browser opens the page from server 1 and then contacting server 2 for the additional code execution it tells web server that

> I brought the page originally from server 1. Is it allowed by you to
>   execute your code in his page?

And the web server 2 needs to be configured (nothing to install AFAIK) with respect to the which are the origin servers that it trusts and which ones doesn't.

The reason it works when everything resides in the same PC is that the origin is the same for both the initial webpage and the extra code of `opener.setearProducto` you wish to call.

Comment: i understand now, thx. i will try with "Cross-document messaging" because i dont need to make a ajax call, only need to pass a text on one script to another